# error: redefinition of class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Here's my code:

```
// in main.cpp

#include "iostream"
#include "circle.cpp"
#include "rectangle.cpp"
#include "shape.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Shape shapes[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (i % 2)
            shapes[i] = Circle(5);
        else
            shapes[i] = Rectangle(10, 10);

        cout << shapes[i].getArea();
    }

    return 0;
}


// in circle.cpp

#include "shape.cpp"

class Circle : public Shape {
    private:
        int radius;
        static const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

    public:
        Circle (int radius) : radius(radius) {}

        virtual int getArea() const {
            return PI * radius*radius;
        };

        virtual int setRadius(int radius){
            radius = radius;
        }
};


// in rectangle.cpp

#include "shape.cpp"

class Rectangle : public Shape {
    private:
        int width;
        int height;

    public:
        Rectangle(int width, int height) : width(width), height(height){}

        virtual int getArea() const {
            return width * height;
        }

        virtual void setWidth(int width){
            this->width = width;
        }

        virtual void setHeigth(int height){
            this->height = height;
        }
};


// in shape.cpp

class Shape {
    public:
        virtual int getArea() const = 0;
};
```

When compiling, I get this error:

```
error: redefinition of 'class Shape'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check out "include guards" or `#pragma once` for compilers that support something like that. It looks like the header may be included several time. And the whole including cpp files... this is not normally how it is done.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should structure your code between .h (headers) and .cpp files (implementation).

You should include header files: `.h`
Never include `.cpp` files. (Unless you know what you do, and that would be in really rare cases).

Otherwise you're ending compiling several times your class, and you get the error your compiler is telling you: 'redefinition of class...'

An additional protection against this error are [Include Guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), or Header Guards.

Most compilers support something of the like `#pragma once` that you write at the top of `.h` files to ensure it is compiled only once.

If the pragma is not available for your compiler, then there is the traditionnal Include/Header guard system:

```
#ifndef MYHEADEFILE_H
#define MYHEADEFILE_H

// content of the header file

#endif
```

Comment: Because otherwise you compile classes several times, and you get the error the compiler is telling you : redefiniton of class .

Comment: @AvivCohn Bad practice, errors like yours, etc. See http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/39618/

Answer (score 17):

Your main.cpp includes files which include shape.cpp, which ends up being included multiple times.  You can avoid this by wrapping your included files with a check for a definition:

```
#ifndef SHAPE_CPP
#define SHAPE_CPP

//file contents

#endif
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Other than it being a bad practice to include cpp files, what's actually wrong with this?

Comment: If you have 3 source files: a.cpp, b.cpp, and common.cpp, where a & b both include common, then things will not be ideal. Once you compile a.o and b.o, you will be unable to link them together to create an executable (let's call it myExe). Why should it be impossible to create an executable that pulls code from two different files, just because the two different files try to use the same library functions? The best thing to do here is to create a.o, b.o, and common.o, then link all of them together into myExe.

Comment: When you compile a.o, b.o, and common.o, at most 1 can have the source code of common.cpp. All of them can have the source code of common.h, though. This pattern is very conducive to never including cpp files, and only including h files.